# Problemas con select option con alcargar datos con petición Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

He realizado un servicio rest realizado con C# con petición ajax en un combo box, este objeto muestra los datos de mi servicio rest, este combo box debe llenar datos de muchas ciudad y este muestra las ciudades que realice en el servicio, pero el inconveniente esta en el objeto combo box o select option en html5, siempre que doy en el objeto, me carga los datos y no puedo seleccionar mi ciudad que quiero, volviéndolo a cargar,  como un bucle infinito cuando deseo seleccionar el dato Anexo código

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback">

                <label>Ciudad</label>
                <select class="form-control" data-rel="chosen"  id="Ciudad" name="Ciudad" onclick="ValidarExisteCiudad()">
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>

            </div>
```

```
function ValidarExisteCiudad() {
    //$("[data-rel='chosen']").chosen();
    //var ddlCiudad = $("[data-rel='chosen']");
    var ddlCiudad = $("#Ciudad");
    ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "CargaCiudad",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
                $.each(data, function () {
                   ddlCiudad.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));

                });
                // After updated data from database you need to trigger chosen:updated.
                //$("[data-rel='chosen']").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },  
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
                existeUsuario = false;
            }
        });




}
```

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CargaCiudad()
        {
            List<Cuidad> Items = await drHelpPrueba.Cuidad.ToListAsync();
            List<SelectListItem> ciudad = new List<SelectListItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ciudad.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = Convert.ToString(Items.ToList()[i].IdCiudad),
                    Text = Items.ToList()[i].Nombre
                });
            }

            return Json(ciudad);

        }
```

Imagen del Combo box

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando deseo seleccionar una ciudad, este vuelve a cargar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No veo porque esperas un resultado diferente al que mencionas si usas el evento `click` del mismo control que estas cargando, al desplegar se ejecuta el evento volviendose a recargar cada vez.

Sino quiere que suceda esto no usas el evento click, podria ser

```
<select class="form-control" data-rel="chosen"  id="Ciudad" name="Ciudad">
</select>
```

y defines la carga al inicio del form

```
<script>
   $(function(){

         ValidarExisteCiudad();

   });

   //aqui defines ValidarExisteCiudad()

</script>
```

al usar el `$(function(){` es el equivalente a `$.ready()` de `jquery` con lo cual se ejecua cuando el DOM del Html este cargado en la pagina o sea seria el `load`

Es en ese momento donde debes cargar el combo, asi al seleccionar un item no se recarga en el click